# Xcode error Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1001f276588)

Tags: ios, xcode

I get the titular error when running my project on an actual device. Sometimes the subcode varies. I don't have ANY breakpoints. I checked. Trust me on that.

[image]

[Here are my files](https://github.com/ghostpotato/SE-UILabel-Nil). This error happens on launch.

What can I do to fix this? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` is printed to the console.

Comment: You should set the exception breakpoint to get the error location in code.

Comment: Add more detail: when is this happening? On launch? In a particular viewcontroller?

Comment: @Robski18 At launch.

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is in this part:

```
let dir = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.AllDomainsMask, true).first 
let filePath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: dir!).URLByAppendingPathComponent("file.txt")
```

It is forced to unwrap "dir", which is probably not available in this case on your actual device. This causes the immediate crash.

Comment: But the above code _is_ what I would use to access files included in my project, right? `file.txt` is one of my project files.

Comment: The file is available in your simulator, but not in the same way in your device. Therefore it gives you the error. I don't know the exact code to solve your issue, but at least you know now where the problem is. Hope that helps!

Comment: Just tried with this code: `let documentsDirectory = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).last!
let fileURL = documentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("file.txt")`, same error. I don't mean to be rude, but if you would mind being a bit more specific on the issue, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem: I was trying to use a variable that was nil. I know that's what the debugger message says, but I figured out which one.

[image]

Oh well. I messed up. Thanks to everyone for all their help!